# Is there an elegant way of delaying evaluation of `A==B` when calling a function that uses this pattern

Tags: functions, function-construction, pattern-matching

Suppose I wanted to define a number of functions that accepts expressions of the form:

`myFcn[x_ >  y_]:= {...does something...};
myFcn[x_ >= y_]:= {...does something...};
myFcn[x_ == y_]:= {...does something else...};
etc...`

But, when `==` is used to call the function, e.g. `C = myFcn[A == B]`, `A == B` is evaluated before it has a chance to be passed on to `myFcn`. This does not happen with other operators, like `<, <=, >`, so I was surprised when it did not worked.

I am aware that I can use `C = myFcn[Unevaluated[A==B]]` to delay evaluation of expression, but this would have to be "rigged" in each function call externally.

Is there a more elegant way of defining the functions so that `==` could be used just as other operators?

Many thanks.

Comment: `myFcn` should have a `Hold*` attribute to do what you want.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `Conditions`'s such as `myFcn[x_ , y_] /; x < y := { ...does stuff...}`, but unfortunately I don't have time to write that up right now.

Comment: I think `<` and `==` should behave the same way in this respect, though, so the issue you're seeing may stem from some other source.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Thanks! It seems to be exactly what I need. I used `SetAttributes[myFcn, HoldAll]` in this application. Would you be so kind to elaborate in case we want to hold one particular input argument out of many unevaluated as oppose to all of them (`HoldAll`), the first one (`HoldFirst`) or all but the first (`HoldRest`), As in `X = myFcn[A, B, C==D, E, ...]`,  holding `C==D` unevaluated while all others use default behavior.

Comment: You should have a look at [the tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html).

Comment: Your definition with  `==`  works for me the same way as `>` or others ... as long as `x` and `y` parameters are symbolic ... Also, are the `{... does something...}` are function of `x` and `y` ? Maybe give a more detailed example ?

Comment: @march - I am using the input patterns as alternative definitions of one function that does many things. The inputs `x_` and `y_` can be many things also, two tensors / scalars, etc... The idea here is that `myFcn` is called using pattern matching but all under the same name. If I were to define a number of different functions, I would do it something like so: `myFcn_ge:=...`, `myFcn_gt:=...`, `myFcn_eq:=...`, and call each when the appropriate condition applies. But I want them all under the same name and not having to deal with inputs prior to function call.

Comment: @Jens - Thanks for the link, I was looking there as soon as I saw the comment regarding `Hold`.

@SquareOne - `x` and `y` are not symbolic in my case and can be tensors of any size. One of the reasons that I mind `==` evaluating before going into the function is that when sizes don't match, it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SetAttributes[myFcn, HoldAll]

myFcn[f_[x_, y_]] := Switch[f,
  Greater, {1, SymbolName[f], x, y},
  GreaterEqual, {2, SymbolName[f], x, y},
  Equal, {3, SymbolName[f], x, y}
  ]

myFcn[A > B]
(* {1, "Greater", A, B} *)

myFcn[A >= B]
(* {2, "GreaterEqual", A, B} *)

myFcn[A == B]
(* {3, "Equal", A, B} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the way to go. Haven't tested it for performance but it gets the job done in an elegant and readable way! +1